# Disabled HTTP access on D-Link Router

Tags: networking, router

I accidentally disabled HTTP access on my D-Link DSL-G225 router by going to Maintenance -> Access Control -> Services and unticking the HTTP on port 80 option.

Now I cannot browse to my router to access its settings. 
Is there any way to enable this setting again without resetting my router?

See screen shot of page where this setting is located:
[image: SCL]

Comment: You disabled it on WAN or on LAN as well? If disabled on both, and if SSH/TELNET are disabled, then I doubt there would be something you can do besides resetting the router.

Comment: How to re-enable http on a D-Link... step 1 Get a hammer. Step 2 smash it into pieces. Step 3 Buy a better router. Done! Seriously though, factory reset it and consider a new device. D-Link is a brand that deserves to be in landfills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your picture, SSH and telnet are also disabled... Assuming you disabled HTTP on both the LAN and WAN, your only choice at this point is performing a hard reset, resetting the unit to factory defaults.

**WARNING!** - This will erase ALL settings in the router, including WiFi SSID and password, any IP address, username, or password changes, and DSL connection settings. These will all have to be setup again manually so make sure you have the necessary information before proceeding.

On the back of the router there is a reset pinhole, with the power connected and the router fully booted up press and hold the button for 5-8 seconds than release it. The router should reboot shortly afterwards and return to a factory out of box state.

After this is completed and the router is booted up, Connect a PC to one of the wired LAN ports and release and renew your DHCP IP settings. If you do do not know how to perform this perform a reboot of your computer.

You should now be able to access the router at `http://192.168.1.1` and use the default username `admin` and password `admin` to access the router and complete the setup necessary for DSL and WiFi connectivity and any other necessary changes such as SSID and setting a WiFi password.

Comment: @DylandeStPern If you find my answer acceptable, please up-vote and accept it (green check) so as to close the question and help others.

Comment: @Dylan de St Pern, this wasn't a comment, it was an answer. If this answer helped you, which I know for a fact this answer is correct. Please Consider marking this as answered so other people searching will find it marked as such. It also gives credit to the person that took their time to answer you. +1

Comment: @acejavelin Is there any possibility of Enabling HTTP access if SSH is already enabled. That is my case. Please let me know ASAP if there is any.

Comment: @ProChess Just ssh to the unit and login, either you will get a menu or a command prompt. If it is a command prompt press ? and enter, but I think your options are pretty limited. If you get a menu, enable http, but most don't have this, certainly not newer devices. I don't think many consumer grade pieces of D-Link hardware have a full shell via ssh either.